# Describe all $\sigma$-algebras of countable set

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Describe all the $\sigma$-algebras of a countable set $X=\{x_1,x_2,...\}$
I cannot understand how can I describe exactly every sigma algebra of a set without it being finite

Comment: Where did this problem come from, or is this just something you were curious about?

Comment: It's certainly possible to describe infinitely many $\sigma$-algebras without talking forever. For example, every subset $A$ of $X$ gives a $\sigma$-algebra $\{\varnothing, A, X-A,X\}$. So I've described uncountably many $\sigma$-algebras. Unfortunately, there are others, so you'll need a different description to get them all. Hint: Think about partitions of $X$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass   I've discovered that, for example, if you have x1 and x2 there exist the following: {∅, X, {x1}, {x2}, {x1, x2}, X-{x1}, X-{x2} , X-{x1,x2} } AND {∅, X, {x1,x2} , X-{x1, x2} }
I can also define for x1,x2,x3 etc. 
But as I get finite number of x's , there are finite sets on the σ-algebra.
So, I'm having a problem in generalizing on how to get infinite sets in a σ-algebra

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro It's mainly a personal concern